# What's an example of an infinitesimal?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, math-history, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

If you want to use infinitesimals to teach calculus, what kind of example of an infinitesimal can you give to the students? What I am asking for are specific techniques for explaining infinitesimals to students, geometrically, algebraically, or analytically.

Note 1. [This page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600634) is related as is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595793).

Comment: This is a political thread, in which you have changed a correct claim (the one you've had trouble contending with in the recent discussions of nonstandard analysis) into a straw-man that is easier to rebut.  The true question was, for the framework of Robinson's nonstandard analysis, in which one defines and evaluate (for example) dy/dx not as a limit but as a ratio of infinitesimals, using an infinitely large or small number $H$ in the process, whether you can give students a concrete example of an individual $H$ ,or how to compute $f(H)$, or how to take the standard part of a bounded $f(H)$.

Comment: @zyx, a concrete example of an infinite number is not that different from a concrete example of an infinitesimal: it is generated by a sequence diverging to infinity, e.g., $(u_n)$ where $u_n=n$.

Comment: Many examples of taking the standard part can be found in Keisler's book starting with page 37; see  https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html

Comment: As the modern consensus is that only nonstandard models have infinitesimals, it will be quite challenging to give a concrete example of one.  It's vaguely analogous to talking about the "field with one element" as a conceptual device and then trying to give a concrete example of such a field.

Comment: I'm not sure. The _[dual numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number)_ are numbers of the form $a+b\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon^2=0$; they can be thought of as elements of $\Bbb R[X]/\langle X^2\rangle$ by identifying $X+\langle X^2\rangle$ with $\varepsilon$. (Unfortunately, division by $\varepsilon$ is undefined.) I would call $\varepsilon$ an infinitesimal. A nice feature of these numbers is that, for any polynomial $p$, we have $p(x+\varepsilon)=p(x)+p'(x)\varepsilon$.

Comment: An example of an infinitesimal quantity, may be given as the ratio of the weight of an ant divided by the weight of the planet earth. For educational purposes, ratios of known things bring in implicit visualization that could lead to understanding.

Comment: "*A user has been claiming at related pages ... that it is impossible to give a meaningful example of an infinitesimal to students*" /// That's false, as @user72694 knows. The user at those related pages said that infinitesimals had been used without problems for centuries, with a rigorous standard definition available since Cauchy as sequences or functions tending to zero. The comments were about infinitely large or small objects in *nonstandard* analysis, and clearly stated as such, with a lot of related arguments the OP prefers to avoid when (mis)quoting.

Comment: "Many examples of taking the standard part can be found in Keisler's book".  Only when it is independent of $H$ (aka standard analysis, taking the limit, or more generally the standard material such as  infinitesimals as things convergent to zero, asymptotics, O notation).  You cannot compute the standard part of $\sin(H)$ for given infinite integer $H$.  We were talking about whether there is a "take standard part" procedure that exists and is usable separate from $f(H)$ and that is a nice test case.

Comment: "*a concrete example of an infinite number is ... generated by a sequence diverging to infinity.*" //  I said this in my very first comment on what you might tell a student and mentioned it in various later comments.  It is a misleading example because it means you either pretend to do nonstandard analysis and actually do standard (which uses sequences in the identical way); or you pretend that "take standard part of $f(H)$" is a separate procedure but can never give meaning to that pretense except in standard examples where a limit exists, never getting beyond good old standard $f(\infty)$.

Comment: (which means we have gone through 100+ comments to demonstrate that my first remark was correct...)

Comment: @zyx, if you don't think one can give a concrete example of an infinitesimal please feel free to provide an *answer* to this question as others have.

Comment: There are two possibilities here.  One is that you managed to ignore the dozens of specific statements that my assertions were exclusively about nonstandard infinitesimals in Robinson's framework, and also ignored the many corrections of your misrepresentation of my comments as discussing infinitesimals in general (for which I cited definitions going back to Cauchy and probably Newton).  The other possibility is that you are deliberately and repetitively lying when you write things like "a user has been claiming ... that it is impossible to give a meaningful example of an infinitesimal".  @us

Comment: @CarlMummert, Francois asked me to clarify your comment which I gladly do.

Comment: @CarlMummert please see this MO question to understand user72694's comment : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227945/what-is-the-modern-consensus-on-the-difficulty-of-infinitesimals

Comment: I respectfully ask @zyx to tone down his comments and to make any actual points of technical content he might have in an answer. Let us keep this civil, can we?

Comment: @AndrejBauer, maybe you missed the history with all the edit revisions and comments and earlier linked threads.  OP is conducting an all-platforms campaign to control online discussion of nonstandard analysis (such as taking over wikipedia, arxiv polemics, endless threads here and in Mathoverflow).  A moderator has already warned the OP that his comments in recent threads constituted gross intentional misrepresentation of other user's remarks (namely mine). There were also snide speculations going beyond that.  If you see a civil way to deal with it short of tedious "doxing" let us know.

Comment: I left a comment at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227945/what-is-the-modern-consensus-on-the-difficulty-of-infinitesimals#comment563320_227945

Comment: See for example the comments immediately below the question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595793/ for remarks on soapboxing, on argumentative behavior of OP, and to witness a so far unsuccessful attempt to get OP to remove aggressive off-topic material from comments.   Some of the silliness was edited out of questions after they were closed (to try to get them reopened) but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent interest in deleting hostile comments.   There's a limit to the amount of one-way restraint that is reasonable before directness is brought into play. @AndrejBauer

Comment: @zyx I did come in late and I am not aware of the history. Anyhow, I am not planning to get dragged into this. I answered the question because I was asked to via email, and I'll leave it at that. Have fun fighting for justice.

Comment: It's fine to be unaware.  Digging the hole deeper afterward, not so much.  You jumping in and others *dragging* you is quite different, is it not? Anyhoo, I just saw that you posted an answer, so thanks for that.  @AndrejBauer

Comment: @AndrejBauer, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 9):

One example of infinitesimals that has been used historically is that of hornangles, which were particularly popular in the 17th century. A hornangle $\alpha$ can be thought of as the "crevice" at the origin between the $x$-axis and the graph of the parabola $y=x^2$. If a real number $r>0$ is represented geometrically by the angle (in the first quadrant) between the $x$-axis and the line $y=r x$, it is easy to convince oneself that $\alpha$ is less than $r$ because a sufficiently short arc of the parabola $y=x^2$ will necessarily dip below the line $y=rx$ (when $r$ is fixed).

In a more arithmetic vein, Skolem in 1933 used sequences of integers to construct an extended number system incorporating infinite numbers. Here an infinite number is represented by a sequence tending to infinity. Skolem's construction does not rely on the axiom of choice. Using the quotient field of Skolem's integers, one gets a number system where a large fragment of calculus can be treated.

Similarly, Keisler in his book https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html on page 913 gives an example of an infinitesimal represented by a sequence tending to zero, such as $(\frac{1}{n})$. Here the infinitesimal represented by $(\frac{1}{n^2})$ will be smaller than the infinitesimal represented by $(\frac{1}{n})$, etc.

Classroom experience shows that students find such examples intuitively appealing.

An additional approach is the one using Levi-Civita fields with the lexicographic ordering. These were used by Shamseddine and colleagues to develop computer implementations with infinity; see http://www.bt.pa.msu.edu/index_cosy.htm  Needless to say, these "nonstandard models" are completely explicit.

As editor @nombre pointed out in a *comment*, the transfer principle is the crux of the matter. Depending on the theory one wishes to transfer, the level of difficulty may vary considerably. For example, if the theory is PA then Skolem's construction in ZF (without relying on the axiom of choice) is enough. If one wishes more powerful tools one will need more foundational input. This is a point often overlooked, even by high-profile people like Connes. The issue of constructiveness of Skolem's procedure is probed in more detail in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227945

Skolem's numbers are relevant because they actually embed in the hyperreals as explained in this article: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-012-9316-5

Teaching experience shows that freshmen react well to examples of infinitesimals as represented by null sequences (i.e., sequences tending to zero). They also have some exposure to equivalence relations usually, so they find comprehensible a comment to the effect that an infinitesimal is not exactly a null sequence but rather an equivalence class of those. Of course the hyperreals cannot be constructed in a freshman calculus class any more than the reals.

Answer (score 7):

The discussion is mostly revolving around Robinson's non-standard analysis, even though the OP has not actually specified what kind of infinitesimals he is looking for. There are definitely good sources on how to teach Robinson's non-standard analysis, but I am not familiar with those, so I cannot say much about that.

Since the purpose is to teach people, it is worth looking at nilpotent infinitesimals, as known in [Synthetic Differential Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_differential_geometry). They quickly give the students methods of calculation that are practically the same as the methods employed by physicists. Synthetic Differential Geometry can be presented axiomatically, without ultrafilters or much attention to the logical language (standard vs. non-standard, internal formulas and). As long as we are interested in concrete computations, we will not even notice the main snag, which is lack of excluded middle.

Here are some references which explain infinitesimals in an accessible way which ought to appeal to students:

1. I highly recommend John Bell's [A primer on infinitesimal analysis](http://books.google.si/books?id=fk1UY6qm8mYC&dq=john+bell+infinitesimal+analysis&pg=PP1&ots=OeqA0XeU95&sig=CXMDUZKBdjXfNneJDN5I4pBiQdQ&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result), or his shorter [An Invitation to Infinitesimal Analysis](http://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/invitation%20to%20SIA.pdf). If you tone down the stuff about intuitionistic logic and just skip to the axioms and computations, you can get a lot of interesting stuff quickly.
2. I apologize for blowing my own horn, but I once wrote a blog post about [intuitionistic mathematics for physics](http://math.andrej.com/2008/08/13/intuitionistic-mathematics-for-physics/#comments) which has a section about infinitesimal analysis. This was targeted at students of physics. There is a [similar exposition](http://math.andrej.com/2014/03/04/intuitionistic-mathematics-and-realizability-in-the-physical-world/) by me in the book [A Computable Universe](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8306).
3. If you teach computer science students you can motivate infinitesimals through the use of [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) in [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), a very cool technique for writing programs that automagically calculate derivatives. You don't quite get "true infinitesimals" but it is a start and it can be quite appealing to computer-sciency students.

You asked specifically how to present to the students infinitesimals, or perhaps how to show them "a concrete" infinitesimal. This is always a bit difficult to do, both in Robinson's non-standard analysis and in Synthetic Differential Geometry. In Robinson's theory things revolve about non-principal ultrafilters, which are probably not the sort of thing you want to teach beginning analysis students. In Synthetic Differential Geometry we have (a squre-nilpotent infinitesimal is defined to be an element of the smooth real line $R$ whose square is zero).

1. $0$ is not the only square-nilpotent infinitesimal: $\lnot \forall x \in R . (x^2 = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0)$.
2. No square-nilpotent is distinct from zero: $\lnot \exists x \in R . x^2 = 0 \land (x < 0 \lor x > 0)$.

These two statements taken together are quite counter-intuitive, especially for a person who is used to classical logic (so 99.99% of mathematicians). The second statement actually tells us that we cannot ever display a concrete infinitesimal that is detectably different from $0$. Infinitesimals are intrinsically strange!
But you can actually take advantage of the oddity and entice students to question some basic assumptions about how their geometric intuitions work and what sort of things are possible in mathematics. It is a lot of fun. I tried to explain the strange status of infinitesimals in my blog post and the paper, so I will not repeat that here.

Comment: 1-2 are intuitive in algebraic geometry as doubled points and lines, which already in pre-rigorous times were thought of as somehow bigger or heavier than ordinary points and lines. The nontriviality of the algebra of dual numbers shows that classical logic and axioms of commutative rings do not suffice to prove "nonzero = invertible", so distinctions 1 and 2 are not exclusively an intuitionistic phenomenon and can be exemplified in classical situations.

Comment: Right. I think the intuitionistic stuff comes in once you are in a *field* and have $x^2 = 0$, and you wonder whether $x = 0$. Intuitionistic fields are messy.

Answer (score 6):

I am teaching a calculus class using infinitesimals, so this question is very relevant for me too, user72694.  I am avoiding formal constructions with ultrafilters and such, because I have found that these are too abstract for my students.  What I want is something more concrete that will allow the students to build a reasonably robust concept image for infinitesimals -- something they can appeal to as necessary when they start working with *dx*s.

So the examples I give them are 0.000...1 (infinity 0s followed by a 1), 0.000...2, 0.000...01, etc.  The reason I like these is that in my research students are able to independently reason with them and to develop conjectures about what happens when you add them, multiply, take ratios, square them, etc.

Of course, if someone asks me what these really *are*, then I will provide a more formal explanation for using sequences (keeping in mind that research shows they don't usually even understand what 0.999... is at this point).  Then I'll talk about how you can think of these infinitesimal decimals as specific sequences of numbers that converge to 0 (there are others like 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ... that I don't know how to write as "decimals").  Ultrafilters etc. arise only when a student figures out that it's actually a bit hairy to compare two convergent sequences where one doesn't strictly dominate the other.

Comment: Nice answer.  I understand you have a published article along these lines.  It may be good to link this if possible.

Comment: The examples with 0.00...1 are either at odds with unique infinite extensions in nonstandard analysis, where the sequence would continue as 0 forever if 0 for all finite positions; or question-begging if interpreted as (0.1)^H for infinite integer H (the question being "what is this infinite H?").  What is the book or logical framework for infinitesiemals used in the class?

Comment: @zyx, we ultimately appeal to the framework in Keisler's textbook, although that is not the course text. I don't think I am viewing these weird decimals in either of the ways you mentioned. I treat 0.000...1 as (1/10, 1/100, 1/1000, ...) and 0.000...01 as (1/100, 1/10000, 1/1000000, ...) -- two different sequences. I think this avoids the logical trouble you mention, but correct me if I'm wrong. The real issue is that you can combine these decimals and get sequences that don't have such weird decimal expansions, so you ultimately have to move to the sequence notation to be more formal.

Comment: A free copy of the research article user72694 mentioned lives here: http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/ely10.pdf

Comment: @zyx, I don't think I mean the same ordinal indexed sums you mention. I think 0.000...1 is 0.1^omega, and 0.000...1 is 0.01^omega.  Does this still cause a problem?

Comment: I don't want to appeal to anything about ordinals. I regret saying "omega" in the previous comment -- my point was simply that the sequences in question are (1/10)^n vs. (1/100)^n, different sequences. These are not transfinitely indexed. Like any plain-old integer-indexed sequences, they can be treated as infinitesimals (as you point out in your answer to the question below). The important thing is that these strange decimals are ones through which students can build intuition, and which can be formalized unambiguously as sequences, which can then be formalized as infinitesimals if needed.

Comment: Is the first example then: (0.1)^H for infinite integer H, at first motivated by informally observing that decimal 0.000...1 should be some power of 1/10, and later writing H as a sequence in what is (maybe secretly) the ultrapower model of NSA?   If so this invites the question "what is an infinite integer" and this is really what needs examples.  That extra stuff can be added to a decimal is very intuitive for students but is not what you seem to actually be doing. It would lead at first to ordinals, maybe with some later adjustment to allow multiplication by 10 or other operations.

Comment: For instance, the student interviewed in your paper understands that smaller and smaller infinitesimal stuff can be added by moving to the right in the decimal expansion, but throughout the (quoted) discussion does not perceive a need to also have spaces to the left of the "1" within the extra post-finite decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

A (relatively) explicit construction of a field with infinitesimal elements via ultraproducts. The problem with the sequences is that the cartesian product of fields
$${\Bbb R}^{\Bbb N} = \Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\cdots$$
isn't a field because has zero divisors:
$$(0,1,0,1,\dots)(1,0,1,0,\dots)=(0,0,0,0,\dots).$$
The solution is taking a quotient: let be $\mathcal U$ a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$. Define
$$(a_1,a_2,\dots)\sim(b_1,b_2,\dots)$$
when
$$\{n\in\Bbb N\,|\,a_n=b_n\}\in\mathcal U$$
The quotient $\Bbb R^* = {\Bbb R}^{\Bbb N}/\sim$ will be a field with infinitesimals, like the class of equivalence of the sequence
$$(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots).$$

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what you believe about the axiom of choice, the fact that there are ordered fields with infinitesimals is provably true. e,g. the field Q[t] of rational functions over Q. Comparing infinitesimals to fields with one element is misleading at best: the statement "there is a field with one element" is provably false.  Fields with one element are suggestive (for example sets would be just vector spaces over these fields) and if any sense is to be made of the concept it would have to be by considering some larger set of structures.

Comment: @CarlMummert try to respond to this if you get a chance.

Comment: Do you seriously think Carl wasn't aware of non-archimedean fields?  The question you are purporting to address here was about Robinson's nonstandard infinitesimals/infinities, and you have fudged that by leaving the word "nonstandard" out of the title.  @user72694

Comment: (sorry to the author of this answer.  You walked into a propaganda campaign by the OP with link web between the different questions.  So things can get a bit weird in the comments.)

Comment: @zyx, my answer was upvoted by 7 editors, whereas Mummert's only by 1 which is presumably yourself judging by the tone of your comment, so it is odd that you would rely too heavily on this.

Comment: @user72694: Bad answers sometimes get many upvotes too. I personally upvoted yours because you mentioned hornangles which I didn't know.

Comment: @nombre, that's fair. It is quite possible that my answer is bad but I was merely pointing out that papal infallibility does not apply nowadays even to editors that zyx approves of :-)

Comment: Francisco, the statement "there is an infinitesimal real number" is also provably false in the axioms that are used in the vast majority of introductory analysis textbooks, which include the Archimedean property of the reals; "there are no infinitesimals in $\mathbb{R}$" is a theorem of the usual texts. Thus, as I said, we must move to nonstandard models to find examples of infinitesimals, but the question asked for examples that could be used in introductory calculus, and so the natural interpretation is to look for infinitesimals in the reals. Those goals are hard to meet simultaneously.

Comment: @Carl Mummert I don't think anybody (that I know of anyway) claims that infinitesimals exist in $\mathbb{R}$. zyx: What the campaign I've wandered into here is, I  haven't quite yet figured out,  but I might need Kurdish militiamen to extricate me. Javier

Comment: @user72694 There are also, currently 4 up and 4 down votes on your question, if that tells you anything you didn't figure out from a moderator's comment (and several upvotes on that) stating that you engage in intentional gross misrepresentation of others' comments.  You can check my user profile to verify that I have never cast a downvote on this site.   This page is the first time I have seen significant **astroturfing** on MSE; 3 answers are from your coauthors, new users who registered today and posted at almost the same time.  The question as posted is of course a farce.

Comment: Mind you, I think it's great if experts join in at whatever number per day per question.  What's unusual is the rallying of (astro) support for the cause, as opposed to concretely answering simple questions about infinite $H$ etc, that might have led to an admission that, yes, NSA has its peculiar difficulties and is not necessariy the Leibnizian best of all possible (infinitesimal) worlds.

Comment: @zyx, I am not a frequent visitor to this forum. Like Javier, I wonder what I've stumbled into! I think the OP invited me to join the conversation because he thought I might have something interesting to add as a math education researcher. That isn't astroturfing, is it? I took the question earnestly, rather than as a farce. For me it is a worthwhile question to ask, and one that influences how I teach.

Comment: @RobEly, arrival of researchers in the discussion is a great thing.  The question, however, is a form of theatrical farce in which (as the OP is attempting to stage it) benighted Bishop Berkeley-style skepticism is disabused by the powers of reason, expertise and pedagogy.   In the linked technical conversations that led to this, some old and some "new" remarks are made about NSA that OP is having a hard time contending with, which is leading to calling out the troops to duly demonstrate the incorrectness of things that were never actually said.  At least it makes for comedy.

Comment: Incidentally, removal of the Note 1, and probably also Note 2, from the question would have made it a perfectly good topic.  As it is, the instant acceptance of an answer that has nothing to do with infinitesimals in calculus (note the subject tags on the question), but begins with the words "no matter what you believe about [AC], the fact that there are ... infinitesimals is provably true" and then contradicts Carl Mummert's remarks, confirms that this question is largely argumentative. The OP also posted on Mathoverflow to dispute Mummert's comment.  All NSA all the time. @RobEly

Comment: zyx it may be worthwhile for you to take heed as far as @AndrejBauer's suggestion is concerned, namely to stay civil.

Answer (score 2):

My pedagogical answer is to explain *one over a generic natural number*.

We cannot explicitly write down a generic natural number just as we cannot explicitly write a generic (non-constructible) irrational number. Like a non-constructible irrational number, it is an abstraction. We do know that it is larger than any fixed integer. We have no algorithmic method to determine any of its non-trivial properties, such as whether it is even or odd, prime or composite. Indeed, we have no algorithmic method to distinguish two different generic natural numbers.

I feel that this approach is close to the infinitesimals of old, and it's also highly intuitive. The notion of one over a generic natural number as an "example of an infinitesimal" comes from  [Kauffman's version of Sergeyev's grossone](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.7545v2.pdf). It also relates to a view I have heard Tim Gowers express online, that a large integer out to be judged by how much we can say about it, and therefore (my words now) that one over a generic natural number is "functionally" an infinitesimal quantity.

Comment: Users interested in some professional assessments of the grossone theory can consult [this thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/226277).

Answer (score 1):

An infinitesimal is some quantity that is explicitly nonzero and yet smaller in absolute value than any real quantity ( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Infinitesimal.html )

Consider a quantity$=1\:$ for example. Then, the half. Then the half of the half. And so on. Of course in continuing to repeat this operation, the quatity tends to $\:0\:$. But a small and more and more smaller quantity always remains to be again divided in two. It's not exactly zero. It is an infinitesimal on the common sens.

More expanation in the above link and in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal

Comment :

In fact, "infinitesimal" is an abstract concept. Think also to another abstract concept : "Infinity" is an unbounded quantity that is greater than every real number. Both abstract concepts cannot be represented in real world on a concrete manner. Nevertheless, they can be intuitively understood.

Comment: Thanks, J. Basically what you seem to be suggesting is that an infinitesimal should be represented by a sequence tending to zero, is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. The sequence tending to zero is only an exemple to produce an infinitesimal as requested. The sequence itself is not an infinitesimal. But the result is an example of infinitesimal : It is a quantity that is nonzero and smaller than any real quantity

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and I agree, a sequence itself is not an infinitesimal but rather *generates* one; that's why I wrote "represented".

Answer (score 1):

An infinitesimal is a positive number whose absolute value is less than any assignable positive number. Observe the word assignable. The difference between assignable and non-assignable  was well understood by the founders of the calculus. It is arrogant to think that the giants like Newton, Lebniz and Euler
did not know that there is no nonzero number whose absolute value is less than any positive real. They bear in mind the fact that there are two kinds of reals. Our concept of standard  is the ancient assignable in a modern logical disguise.

When one asks for an example of infinitesimal  which is the inverse of an infinite and says there are no such, he  mocks himself for the numbers are mental constructions, and there are no numbers independent of human beings. That is, he cannot give an example of any number in much the same way as  he knows no "real" examples of infinitely large and infinitely  small numbers.

If we think about the numbers expressing the quantity of molecules in a room or if we count the grains of sands on a beach, then we see that these numbers are unreachable  in contract to the number of fingers. The natural series starts with assignable numbers but there are clearly some  numbers that are practically unreachable by successive count. These examples explain the difference between standard or assignable and non-standard or non-assignable numbers on a naïve level.

Comment: Very nicely put, thanks.  The technical implementation of these intuitions about infinitesimals is of course Ed Nelson's Internal Set Theory where infinitesimals are found within the ordinary real line itself.

Answer (score 1):

To define "infinitesimal" as either

- a **sequence or function that converges to zero**

or

- as an *adjective* for describing such a sequence or function

is a very old tradition that goes back in some form to Cauchy's Cours de Analyse or earlier, and is consistent with (if not necessarily the same as) statements in writings of old masters since Newton.  If supplemented with ideas and notation from asymptotic analysis it can do most of what was accomplished with infinitesimal arguments before the rise of abstract analysis in the 20th century.

Of course it is easy to give examples of things that converge to 0.

Comment: You should see this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22400/166353

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, I had already informed this user of the post at the time using @

Comment: @zyx, this is a bit more complicated than that.  Cauchy said that a sequence converging to zero *becomes* an infinitesimal rather than *is* an infinitesimal.  The idea that he meant a null sequence to generate an infinitesimal is confirmed by the fact that he was interested in rates of growth of sequences and even tried to classify those.  In his textbook *Cours d'Analyse* he formulates and proves a series of results all of which focus on asymptotic behavior. Thus his *procedures* were distinctly non-archimedean, as were Leibniz's.

Comment: Since Euler if not earlier there was the more general idea of asymptotic behavior (vs convergence or nullness) and I don't know to what extent those are distinguished by anyone before the mid-1800's.   But would Cauchy have objected to the adjectival form "an infinitesimal sequence" as opposed to the words "an infinitesimal *is* a sequence such that ..."?  Apart from what Cauchy might have said or done, using convergent to 0 as a definition of infinitesimal is done in some older books (not older than Cours d'Analyse, old relative to today).

Comment: @zyx, I appreciate your calm tone. I am not sure what you are asking, though.  As I mentioned earlier, in most cases Cauchy does *not* write "an infinitesimal *is* a sequence", but rather that "a sequence *becomes* an infinitesimal. I would describe this as some kind of reification for lack of a better term. Today we would understand this in terms of equivalence relations but Cauchy did not have those yet. I find Detlef Laugwitz's analysis of Cauchy in his 1987 article in *Historia Mathematica* very perceptive.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: The infintesimals simulated here are close to finite approximations of real numbers. aka: finite numbers

Python3 code that simulates infintesimals using surreal representation

```
nan = ()
bits = 16

def construct(num):
   if num is None: return nan
   seed  = nan,nan
   power = 0
   while num != 0 and 2**-bits <= abs(num):
      if num > 0:
         num -= 1/2**power
         seed = seed,seed[1]
      else:
         num += 1/2**power
         seed = seed[0],seed
      if abs(num) < 1:
         power += 1
   return seed
```

surreal representations are created like this:

```
construct(29.75)
```

this routine compares representations

```
def le(a,b):
   l,r = a[0],b[1]
   return not(l and le(b,l) or r and le(r,a))
```

surreal representations are compared like this:

```
le(construct(1/3),construct(27/79))
```

The infintesimal routines generate representations that will compare closer to the input number than any number that could be created by construct.

```
def pos_infintesimal(a):
   inf = []
   inf[:] = [(a),inf]
   return inf

def neg_infintesimal(a):
   inf = []
   inf[:] = [inf,(a)]
   return inf
```

create two infintesimals close to pi...

```
from math import pi

surreal_pi = construct(pi)
pos_inf_pi = pos_infintesimal(surreal_pi)
neg_inf_pi = neg_infintesimal(surreal_pi)
```

now neg_inf_pi < surreal_pi < pos_inf_pi, and there is no surreal number you can make using construct() that will come between them.

As a minimum, these will be true and no finite construction will come between them.

```
le(neg_inf_pi,surreal_pi)
le(surreal_pi,pos_inf_pi)
```

And also, this will be False (so they are not equal)

```
le(pos_inf_pi,surreal_pi)
le(surreal_pi,neg_inf_pi)
```

And there is no number that comes between them, so this should not be true for any x:

```
n = construct(x)
le(neg_inf_pi,n) and le(n,surreal_pi) or le(surreal_pi,n) and le(n,po_inf_pi)
```

The reason is that every result from construct() is a finite limited structure. But the infintesimal values are self referential, so they have unlimited bounds for traversing.

Answer (score -1):

For this Q (the existence of a concrete, meaningful infinitesimal) to have a mathematical meaning, one has to specify the structure (a non-archimedean extension of $\mathbb R$) wrt which the Q is considered. If it is a typical Robinson-style ultrapower of $\mathbb R$ then the method described by Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla gives you a lot of concrete infinitesimals in such an ultrapower. One can also name concrete infinitesimals, in different manner, in typical pre-Robinson non-archimedean fields like Levi-Civita.

In the other direction, one can probably ask if there is a non-archimedean extension of $\mathbb R$ with no real-ordinal definable (ROD) infinitesimals, and I wonder if one can get such an extension in the Solovay model

Comment: Finding proper extensions of the ordered field of the real numbers with "explicit" (at least definable in ZF) infinitesimals is not difficult. (for instance,  $\frac{1}{X}$ in $\mathbb{R}(X)$ ordered so that $X$ is infinite)

 What is more difficult is finding elementary extensions which satisfy the transfer principle over the copy of the set of reals.

Comment: @nombre, nice comment.  The transfer principle is indeed the crux of the matter.  Note that depending on the theory you want to transfer, the level of difficulty may vary considerably. For example, if you want PA then Skolem's construction in ZF (without relying on choice) is enough.  If you want more powerful tools you need more foundational input.  This is a point often overlooked in this type of discussion, even by leading people like Connes. If you like the answer don't forget to upvote it.